# Converted date format inconsistent after loading into destination table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am using a merge statement to load data where I have to calculate and convert a date field and load into a varchar column in the dest table

```
MERGE dbo.DestTable AS Target
    USING (
    SELECT ID, 
    MAX(CAST(CONVERT(date,dateadd(day, CAST(date as int),'1960-01-01'))AS VARCHAR(30))) date,
    max(col1) col1,
    max(col2) col2
    FROM dbo.Staging
    GROUP BY  ID
    )
    AS Source
    ON ( Target.ID = Source.ID )
    WHEN MATCHED THEN 
        UPDATE SET  Target.Date = Source.date,
                    Target.col1= Source.col1,
                    Target.col2= Source.col2,

    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN 
        INSERT (ID
               ,Date
               ,col1
               ,col2
               )
        VALUES (
                    Source.ID,
                    Source.date,
                    Source.col1,
                    Source.col2
                    );
```

Just running the select statement gives me the second output and querying the destination table gives the first output. The destination column is of the same datatype as the final converted source field.

Output is in the link below

[image: date format inconsistency]

I have tried scouring the net for a solution as well but haven't found much to help. I would really appreciate it if someone could tell me where I'm going wrong. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You seem to be using some sort of datatype that isn't a date or datetime in both tables. This is root of the problem.

Comment: The destination type is a varchar and for some reason that is the desired type as this table would be referenced for further calculations in another application. The source is float (in seconds from epoch date) which i converted to a valid date and then converted that to varchar. The format in the second image is desired. The format on top is what is written into the table. Half of the rows are as desired and the other half in a different format and truncated.

Comment: `MAX()` of a `VARCHAR()` will alphabetize the results, i.e. "10" is less than "2". Is that what you're _trying_ to do?

Comment: The dataset is index by a unique combination of two fields (ID, another_field). For every unique ID all the other fields are repeated. So essentially max(), min() or avg() is the same value. But to pick up only unique ID columns i was doing a GROUP BY ID and max(col1,col2,...) which would essentially give me the single value.